# How to use jQuery to load pages in new window in order then close them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a CMS and in order for the tags that this CMS uses to work I need to load all of the pages, including some that aren't found directly on the site. This is a one time thing so it doesn't really matter, but I thought it would be fun to make a function for this.

I want to create a link that when clicked will open and load a series of pages in order and then close them.

```
<a href="#" id="#load">Click here to load the pages!</a>

<script>
    $('#load').click(function() {
        window.open('www.google.ca');
    });
</script>
```

The above code should open one page, how would I add more pages and can I make the script close the pages?

Comment: `var myWindow = window.open('www.google.ca');
myWindow.close();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What about adding more pages to open and close?

Comment: Do you want to open them and immediately close? Or on another click?

Comment: I just need the pages to load and then close, so immediately, maybe after a timeout of a second?

Comment: @user3153169 make it in an answer below so I can click the check mark after =)

Comment: You cannot open more than one page without facing browser popup blocker. Your user then need to allow it. Popup can only be opened reacting user interaction, one at a time

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for the feedback, maybe the pages can be loaded in the background with php instead of popping up? The pages will be closing any ways, will it allow them to show and then try to close them itself or will it just not allow the script to open the windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sites = ["www.google.ca", "www.google.com"];

$("#load").click(function(){
    var windows = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++){
        var wd = window.open("http://" + sites[i]);
        windows.push(wd);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++){
            windows[i].close();
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F7B3G/)

BUT, as A. Wolff said, the browsers block windows if you open more then 1 and only works if user enables the popups for the site.

Comment: My friend, through testing your script, it just loads my website with each page being opened as "www.example.com/0", with each extra page being 1, 2, 3, 4, etc? It also doesn't close any of the pages.

Comment: apparently the loop does not work like this. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare array to hold all windows. And iterate it to close like below:

```
var window_arr = new Array();

<script>

 // Code to open all windows    

  $('#load').click(function() {
    window_arr.put(window.open('www.google.ca'));
  });

// code to close all windows

 for (var window in  window_arr ) {
  window_arr[window].close();
  }
```